# i am CommandNotFoundException?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, compiler-errors

Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes. If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.

PS C:\Web Development> scss --style expanded "c:\Web Development\bootstrap Demo\bootstrap-5.1.3\bootstrap-5.1.3\scss_variables.scss"
scss : The term 'scss' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- scss --style expanded "c:\Web Development\bootstrap Demo\bootstrap-5. ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scss:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

i am expecting to compile my bootstrap after adding an color to it.

Comment: Run `scss` in the same directory you installed it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `scss` isn't a command. I believe you're looking for the `sass` command.

**NOTE:** This uses the SCSS syntax by default, not the indented Sass syntax.